# How to code arrows from one letter to another letter? like in the image below. How do I code arrows from letter U to X?

Tags: arrows, code

[image]

If you look at the image below, How do I code arrows from letter U to X?

Comment: My fee goes up 150% for very urgent matters. :-) What have you tried/researched so far? What package(s) do you use for graphics and/or diagrams?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that sets up the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  In this case, the solution is highly dependent on how you are drawing the given image. So, if you are using `tikz-cd` then you have an answer. Otherwise, please set up a MWE with the portions of the diagram that you can do.

Answer (score 6):

It takes just a few minutes into the manual of `tikz-cd`. Do `texdoc tikz-cd` or go to http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
&&& U \arrow[dl] \arrow[dr] \\
Z \arrow[rr] && X \arrow[rr] && Y
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution without using TikZ:

```
\vbox{\halign{&\hfil$#$\hfil\cr
                      & \ U \cr \noalign{\kern-.25em}
                      & \swarrow \ \searrow \cr
   Z \longrightarrow\ & X \longrightarrow Y \cr 
}}

\bye
```

[image: arrows]